# In what sense does a divisor actually divide?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

So I've been stuck for the past couple of days trying to figure out how a divisor in algebraic geometry is actually, in some sense, analoguous to a divisor in elementary number theory. I cannot help but feel that if I understood this, I would have an easier time understanding the "point" of the concept.

Several texts give hints at the connection. In Eisenbud's wonderful *Commutative Algebra: with a view toward Algebraic Geometry* the Berkeley professor writes (p. 262-3):

> If $a,b$ are elements of a ring, then $b$ divides $a$ iff $a \in (b)$. In general, an ideal can be regarded as something by which an element might be divisible--a "divisor." Because of the unique factorization into prime ideals in a Dedekind domain, nonzero ideals there correspond to finite sets of codimensions 1 prime ideals, each with multiplicity. The term *divisor* was transferred to such sets and stuck there.

Which of course brings to mind Kummer's original idea when he first defined *ideal numbers* which Dedekind eventually repurposed to our modern notion of an ideal. Nevertheless, I am still far from grasping the connection fully.

Specifically, if $V$ is some variety and $C$ is a Weil divisor of $V$, then how does $C$ "divide" $V$?

Comment: The text you have cited is very clear answering your question.

Comment: Well, err-... I still don't get it, I'm afraid. Hence why I'm asking the question. Please help me.

Comment: I would say that if $f$ is a rational function on $V$, then the vanishing locus of $f$ is a codimension 1 subset, and $f$ vanishes along a divisor $C$ if and only if $f$ is in the maximal ideal of the local ring $O_C$. If $C$ is a Cartier divisor, then $O_C$ is a DVR and this vanishing condition is also equivalent to $f$ being *divisible* by the uniformizer, a.k.a “the local equation of $C$”.

Comment: You might prefer the terminology of “$C$ is a divisor *on* $V$” rather than “divisor *of* $V$”. It’s a divisor of various rational functions on $V$, it doesn’t “divide the variety” (that is not a concept).

Answer (score 3):

As Jake Levinson mentioned in comment, you should think of $C$ as a divisor **on** $V$ rather than divisor *of* V.

Maybe this example on $V = \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ would help.

- Irreducible divisors in this case are the (usual) primes $(p)$.
- A Weil divisor $C$ is then a formal sum $C = \sum e_p (p)$, where $e_p \in \mathbb{Z}$.
- A positive integer $n$ is then a global section/function on $V$. If the prime factorization of $n = \prod_p p^{e_p}$, then the principal divisor $div(n)$ is exactly $\sum e_p (p)$. This may more closely match with your intuition of "divisors".

Since you mentioned ideal numbers, you can play the same game with Spec of integers in a number field. The irreducible divisors is in that case correspond to prime ideals of your integers, and principal divisors again correspond to a factorization of principal ideal into product of primes.